# Função que retorna primeiro elemento de uma lista

Tags: lista, lisp

Estou a tentar fazer uma função que irá retornar o primeiro elemento de uma lista em Clisp.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```lisp
(defun pr(NomeDaCidade X Y)
    (first '(NomeDaCidade X Y)))
```

E ao tentar chamar da forma:

```lisp
(pr '('Lisboa' 3 4))
```

O Clisp rebenta.
Não estou a conseguir identificar o meu erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Faz **muito** tempo que não mexo com Lisp, mas pelo pouco que me lembro:*</sup>

```lisp
(defun pr(NomeDaCidade X Y)
```

Aqui você define uma função que recebe 3 parâmetros (e não uma lista). Sendo assim, para obter somente o primeiro elemento, nem precisaria criar uma lista e chamar `first`, bastaria fazer:

```lisp
(defun pr(NomeDaCidade X Y)
    NomeDaCidade)

(pr "Lisboa" 3 4) ; chama a função com 3 parâmetros
```

Repare que ao chamar a função, passamos os 3 parâmetros separadamente, em vez de passar uma lista com eles. **Mas essa é uma função bem inútil**, já que ela ignora os outros 2 parâmetros (a menos, é claro, que ela use `X` e `Y` para outas coisas, antes de retornar o nome da cidade).

---

Se a ideia é receber uma lista, então a função só deve ter um parâmetro, que é a lista. Aí você retorna somente o primeiro elemento dela:

```lisp
(defun pr(lista)
    (first lista))

(pr '("Lisboa" 3 4)) ; chamar função passando uma lista com os valores
```

Agora sim eu chamo a função passando uma lista, e dentro dela eu pego somente o primeiro elemento.

---

Claro que a função acima ainda é meio inútil, pois estou ignorando os demais elementos. Mas você poderia pegá-los assim:

```lisp
(defun pr(lista)
    ; obtém os elementos da lista e coloca-os em variáveis
    (setq nomeCidade (first lista)
          x (nth 1 lista)
          y (nth 2 lista))

    ; supondo que a função faz outras coisas com x e y ...

    nomeCidade) ; retorna o primeiro elemento

(pr '("Lisboa" 3 4)) ; passar uma lista com os valores
```